# What's the accepted practice when you downvote an answer and the question is edited so the answer fits?

Tags: discussion, edits, down-votes

I came across this today. [How to put a div at center of another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475550/how-to-put-a-div-at-center-of-another-div) was [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1475550/list) asking how to have "one div at center of another div vertically". I downvoted an answer that said to use "margin: 0 auto" and adding a DOCTYPE, which is what you do for horizontal centering. The question was later changed to say horizontal. The answer wasn't but a downvote is no longer appropriate.

What's the appropriate action in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The question was initially unclear (he wrote "vertically" but indicated that the method for centering horizontally worked for him in FF, thus hinting that he may have actually meant "horizontally").

Since it was corrected, and you saw the correction, you should probably remove your down-vote. (i suspect you've already done this, given the edit...)

Comment: That is indeed what I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have edit privileges, there is nothing you can do.  Your vote is cast, it's permanent, you could leave a comment explaining that you're sorry that you downvoted earlier, but that's about it.

On the other hand, echoing Shog9, if you have edit privilege, edit it and change your vote.  Problem solved.